# How to create singleton instances of object based on a parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, singleton, closures

I need to create a singleton implementation of an object which should only return the same object if its parameter(example, doc_id) remains the same otherwise if the doc_id changes then create and new instance with doc_id property.

Example-

```
var object;
function mysingletonObj(obj){
    obj = obj || {};
    object.doc_id = obj.doc_id || 'default';
    object.timeoutDuration = obj.timeoutDuration || 3000;

    // i need to return a new object if obj.doc_id is new and there is
    // no other instace of Object with same doc_id otherwise return
    // that instance with same doc_id

    return{
       getInstance: if(!object){
         return object;
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: please check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40276766/2545680) and let me know if it's what you're looking for

Comment: did my answer help?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Maximus I also turned up with kind of similar solution...it helped!

Comment: you're welcome. you can accept my answer if it helped then)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Singleton = (function () {
    var instance;
    var parameter;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new Object("I am the instance");
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function (doc_id) {    
            if (!instance || doc_id !== parameter) {
                instance = createInstance();
                parameter = doc_id;
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();


var instance1 = Singleton.getInstance(doc_id);
```